# === php laravel operator not working in cent os 6.9

Tags: php, centos

=== operator is not working in the PHP-Laravel website installed on CENT OS 6.9 server as per the below code.

```
{{ $abc_history->abc_status === 4 && $abc_history->status === 2 ? 'success' : ($abc_history->abc_status === 0 ? 'danger' : ($abc_history->abc_status === 1 ? 'active-dash' : ($abc_history->abc_status === 4 && $abc_history->status === 1? 'active-dash' : '')))}}
```

Comment: Are you sure the variable `$this->abc_history->abc_status` is a integer? Please check with a `var_dump($this->abc_history->abc_status)`

Comment: the variable values are working perfectly with == operator

Answer (score 0):

Because with `==` operator: `"4" == 4 return true`, but in `===` operator `"4" === 4 return false`.

Comment: In Database the value is integer type, therefore 4 === 4 must return true